# how to obtain log from other library in android studio ( Java)

Tags: java, android

I am creating an app and using some 3rd-party library, In android Monitor tab in Android Studio I can see some debug log print out for information. I dont have control of this library, I can only use certain APIs exposed by the library. **I would like to know how i can retrieve the log from android monitor** so that i can put the log into one of my textview to display in the app. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command to dump the log file

```
$adb logcat -d > logcat.txt
```

Then you can access this file from your application to show the logged data

Comment: Can you provide more context how to retrieve this in the IDE? I am thinking about using runtime.exeu to run the command and load the file back in the app. But that seems not very straight-forward.